# defining variable names with counters in python

Tags: python

I am trying to assign every letter in the given word 'cmpny' to an undefined variable(here, i am using counters as variable)

```
var_counter = 0
user_input = 'cmpny'
for usr in user_input:
    var_counter = var_counter + 1
    (var_counter_'%d' %var_counter) = usr
    print(var_counter'%d'%var_counter)
```

Here, I want this to appear as follows:

```
var_counter_1 = c
var_counter_2 = m
var_counter_3 = p
var_counter_4 = n
var_counter_5 = y
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Please check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var_counter = 0
user_input = 'cmpny'

for usr in user_input:
  var_counter +=1
  tempVar = "var_counter_"+str(var_counter)
  globals()[tempVar] = usr
```

It will create variables like var_counter_1,var_counter_2,....

You can check the output by using:

```
print(var_counter_1)
print(var_counter_2) and so on
```

or by using loop

```
for i in range(1,len(user_input)+1):
   print(eval("var_counter_"+str(i)))
```